# Como autoenviarme un SMS que aparente ser de una compañia

Tags: android, sms

necesito crear pin de activación por medio de SMS, tengo el PIN de cada usuario en la BDD, puedo traerlo sin problema. ¿Como hago que al recibir eso genere un SMS automáticamente donde contenga el PIN que se trajo?.

Comment: ¿Que pruebas has realizado?

Answer (score 1):

Para poder enviar SMS desde tu aplicación necesitas disponer de una **Pasarela SMS** (casi siempre de pago)

La forma más sencilla de acceder a la puerta de enlace SMS de un buen proveedor de servicios de SMS es hacerlo a través de una API.

Normalmente *el proveedor de servicios de SMS cuenta con unas API propias* que pone a disposición de sus usuarios. A través de ellas, la integración a la SMS Gateway se convierte en una operación sencilla y rápida.

---

También puedes usar tu propio movil Android en una pasarela SMS mediante:
https://smsgateway.me/

Necesitas instalar una parte en tu movil Android y descargar las librerias PHP para su uso https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-libraries/sms-gateway-me-php.zip

---

Tambien dispones de otros SMS Gateway, de código libre para lo implementes tu mismo como https://playsms.org

Comment: Pero la pregunta es como realizarlo,  ¿Como lo puede realizar, puedes agregar un ejemplo?